# regex to exclude if preceded by string?

Tags: c#, regex

I haven't used regex much before but found something useful on the net that I'm using:

```
private string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string msg)
{
    string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\\||\# |!|\(|?|\[|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
    Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Click to open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www").Replace(@"\r\n", "<br />").Replace(@"\n", "<br />").Replace(@"\r", "<br />");
}
```

It does a good job but now I want it to exclude urls that already have a "a href=" in front. There's the ending "/a" to consider too.

Can that be done with regex or have to use totally different approach, like coding?

Comment: I think you could use negative look ahead to exclude href=.  I think it's (?!href=) or something like that.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks suspiciously like you're trying to use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @spender -- that post about parsing html with regex is my favorite.

Comment: @Uncle Iroh thanks but where to put that exactly, tried with regexr.com no luck yet.

Comment: @spender well it's not making me a sandwich right now... useless!

Comment: @colinlamarre Have you read [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=votes#1732454) spender and Uncle Iroh talk about? I [recommend](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267993/why-people-do-not-carefully-read-my-question-even-after-a-spending-a-bounty/268153#268153) you to rewrite your post without HTML sample - it generally bad idea to parse HTML with regex -  HtmlAgilityPack (and maybe +`Uri` class in your case) is generally better approach if you care about result not the learning regex part.

Comment: yeah, cause of it's global nature I'm not having much luck with negative look ahead and negative look behind isn't allowed in javascript.  Sorry mate.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov that post was too funny! I was heading for a melt down according to him, but not really, only dealing with urls here not tons HTML.

Comment: @Uncle Iroh it's good cuz .net regex supports lookbehind, found debuggex.com which supports it too in python mode.  Still not obvious tho :) i sense a melt down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((?<!href=')(?<!href=")(www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\\||\# |!|\(|?|\[|,| |>|<|;|\)])
```

I tested on regex101.com

With the following sample set:

```
www.google.com
http://hi.com
http://www.fishy.com
href='www.ignore.com'
www.ouch.com
```

Comment: the big problem was those websites, they're not working properly it seems, .net does a better job. So how to tell it to skip to the ending "/a" now?

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing regex pattern you could make a few simple changes to handle additional text being prepended or appended to your string:

```
`.+` <- pattern -> `(.+)?`
```

Which would give you:

```
.+((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\\||\# |!|\(|?|\[|,| |>|<|;|\)])(.+)?
```

So passing the string of either:

```
<a href='http://www.test.com'>http://www.test.com</a>
```

...or...

```
http://www.test.com
```

Would result in:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com" title="Click to open in a new window or tab" target="&#95;blank">www.test.com</a>
```

Examples:

https://regex101.com/r/bO0cW6/1

http://ideone.com/suVw3I

Comment: thanks but the urls are buried in the middle of up to 65k data, so how to tell it between "a href" and "/a"?

Comment: @colinlamarre, I'm not sure that I follow; if you provide an example string of what you mean maybe that would help.

Comment: it's just say paragraphs of text with some urls in the middle, some have href already, some dont, but the goal is make them all have hrefs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a little ToNy tHe pOny to do that in regex after all, so wrote the code, in case anyone is interested here it is:

```
private string handleatag(string msg, string tagbegin, string tagend)
{
    ArrayList tags = new ArrayList();
    int tagbeginpos = msg.IndexOf(tagbegin);
    int tagendpos;

    string hash = tagbegin.GetHashCode().ToString();

    while (tagbeginpos != -1)
    {
        tagendpos = msg.IndexOf(tagend, tagbeginpos);

        if (tagendpos != -1)
        {
            string atag = msg.Substring(tagbeginpos, tagendpos - tagbeginpos + tagend.Length);
            msg = msg.Replace(atag, hash + tags.Count.ToString());
            tags.Add(atag);
        }
        else
            msg = msg.Remove(tagbeginpos, tagbegin.Length);

        tagbeginpos = msg.IndexOf(tagbegin, tagbeginpos);
    }

    msg = ConvertUrlsToLinks(msg);

    for (int i = 0; i < tags.Count; i++)
        msg = msg.Replace(hash + i.ToString(), tags[i].ToString());

    return msg;
}

private string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string msg)
{
    if (msg.IndexOf("<a href=") != -1)
        return handleatag(msg, "<a href=", "</a>");

    string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\\||\# |!|\(|?|\[|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
    Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Click to open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www").Replace(@"\r\n", "<br />").Replace(@"\n", "<br />").Replace(@"\r", "<br />");
}
```